# Java Spring Data @Autowired issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a Java project based on Spring Data and Spring.

I have a Spring bean and Spring data repository autowired into it. And I want this bean to be injected to itself as a field.

My bean is:

```java
@Service @Transactional public class JobService {

    @Autowired private ChatMessagesRepository chatMessagesRepository;
}
```

But, if I try to inject this bean into itself, all Spring Data  (and I believe others beans) becomes `null`, autowiring crashes. Why may it happen?

My config:

```xml
....
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="..."
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory"
                      transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="...">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                                expression="org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration"/>
    </context:component-scan>
....
```

Comment: This is a sIngleton bean

Comment: I am not sure but ,did you try other scope ?

Comment: Because I want one method in JobService to be called by other method in this class in REQUIRES_NEW transaction, but if I call just one method from another, the transaction will be the same.

Comment: This will not work, because the bean I will get via applicationContect will be the same, and transactin will be the same as well. I don't understand, why self-injecting doesn't work? Spring version is 4.3.1

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject a bean into itself, it would be a cycle.

There are four solutions:

- cut your bean into two beans (best approach)
- use AspectJ
- couple your code to Spring with [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html)
- couple your code to Spring with [`AopContext`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AopContext.html)

See [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies):

> This means that method calls on that object reference will be calls on the proxy, and as such the proxy will be able to delegate to all of the interceptors (advice) that are relevant to that particular method call.
>   However, once the call has finally reached the target object, the `SimplePojo` reference in this case, any method calls that it may make on itself, such as `this.bar()` or `this.foo()`, are going to be invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a chance to execute.
>
> Okay, so what is to be done about this? The best approach (the term best is used loosely here) is to refactor your code such that the self-invocation does not happen. For sure, this does entail some work on your part, but it is the best, least-invasive approach. The next approach is absolutely horrendous, and I am almost reticent to point it out precisely because it is so horrendous. You can (choke!) totally tie the logic within your class to Spring AOP by doing this:
>
> ```
> public class SimplePojo implements Pojo {
>
>    public void foo() {
>        // this works, but... gah!
>        ((Pojo) AopContext.currentProxy()).bar();
>    }
>
>    public void bar() {
>        // some logic...
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> This totally couples your code to Spring AOP, and it makes the class itself aware of the fact that it is being used in an AOP context, which flies in the face of AOP.
>
> [...]
>
> Finally, it must be noted that AspectJ does not have this self-invocation issue because it is not a proxy-based AOP framework.

Answer (score -2):

Autowired applies to public variables or methods

```
@Service @Transactional public class JobService {

    private ChatMessagesRepository chatMessagesRepository;

    @Autowired public void setChatMessagesRepository(ChatMessagesRepository chatMessagesRepository) {
        this.chatMessagesRepository = chatMessagesRepository;
    }
}
```